# Python: What's the "Pythonic" way to process two lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have this code in Python. I'm a Perl programmer, as you may be able to tell.

```
# Both list1 and list2 are a list of strings
for x in list1:
  for y in list2:
    if y in x:
      return True
return False
```

What's a more Pythonic way to handle this? I assume a list comprehension could do it well, but I can't get my head around the "process two separate lists" part of this.

Comment: Is ``list`` really a list of lists or tuples that means you have to use the ``in`` operator?

Comment: list1 and list2 are lists of strings. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Given that list1 and list2 are lists of strings, the code above returns `True` if there exists a string in `list1` that is a substring of `list2`. If you want to check if the same string exists in both list1 and list2, then either use `if y==x` or better yet, replace all of your code with `return frozenset(list1).intersect(frozenset(list2))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert two nested loops into a nested comprehension, you just do this:

```
[<expression> for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

If you've never thought through how list comprehensions work, the tutorial [explains it](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.

In other words, the clauses from left to right in a comprehension match up with statements from top/outside to bottom/inside, and that's all there is to it.

[This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/comprehensions-for-dummies.html) attempts to put the same idea in yet another way, in case you haven't got it yet.

---

But here, you don't have an expression, you have a statement.

But you have an expression in there, the `y in x` part of the statement, and what you want to do is return True if it's every true for any value, which is exactly what `any` does. So:

```
return any([y in x for x in list1 for y in list2])
```

---

And really, you don't want to build the list here, just iterate over the values, so drop the square brackets to make it a generator expression instead:

```
return any(y in x for x in list1 for y in list2)
```

---

For the simple case of just iterating the cartesian products of multiple iterables, you may want to use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead. In this case, I don't think it makes things any simpler or more readable, but if you had four lists instead of two—or an unpredictable-in-advance number of them—that might be a different story:

```
return any(y in x for x, y in product(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 4):

No, a list comprehension can't do it well. You want a boolean result, list comprehensions are for creating lists (and they don't really do early exit). You could use a generator comprehension:

```
return any(y in x for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2))
```

or if you really like using standard libraries for everything (or you think like a functional programmer):

```
from itertools import starmap, product
from operator import contains

return any(starmap(contains, product(list1, list2))
```

Comment: I don't think `product` really adds anything here… but it obviously would if there were a dynamic number of lists instead of exactly two, or even just a large static number.

Comment: @abernert: I don't think it's a big deal, but it has the slight benefit that it declares up front that the thing iterated over in the second `for` is independent of the value you're currently working with in the first `for`. Explicit is better than can-be-worked-out-by-peering-at-the-code, or some such slogan :-)

Comment: Yes, and that's part of the reason it's useful with a larger number. I just think in a trivial case, the expression is short enough that `list2` being independent of `x` is so obvious that using `product` adds more complexity than it removes.

Comment: @abarnert: well, if you mildly dislike my first alternative then you'll strongly dislike the second ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Steve and abamarts answers are explaining what you asked explicitly, i would try to address what you implied regarding list comprehensions.

A "nested" list comprehension is nothing more then your original nested for loop, but with the twist, that the most inner-block moves up to the top!

```
for x in list1:
  for y in list2:
    if y in x:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

becomes:

```
[True if y in x else False for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

So the for-loops remain more or less in order:

```
[for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

then prepend the if-clause:

```
[if y in x else False for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

and finally prepend the result for the if-statement to be True:

```
[True if y in x else False for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

a nested example:

```
tpl_list = []
for element in vector:
    for x, y in element:
       if (x**2+y**2) < 1:
          tpl_list.append((1/x, 1/y))
       else:
          tpl_list.append((x,y))
```

as a list comprehension (building in steps)

```
[for e in vector for x,y in e]
[if (x**2+y**2) < 1 else for e in vector for x,y in e]
[(1/x, 1/y) if (x**2+y**2) < 1 else (x,y) for e in vector for x,y in e]
```

Comment: Why are you writing `True if y in x else False` when you could write `y in x`?

Comment: To demonstrate the order if it isn't so easy! See last example! But i like the knowledge, that every post is combed with a very fine brush! ;-)

Comment: @DonQuestion: This is more misleading than helpful. Turning an `if` statement into an `if` expression is entirely independent of turning a nested series of statements into a nested comprehension. And your description is wrong—it's not the most inner block that moves to the front, but the expression controlled by the most inner block. If you wanted the `if` statement to be part of the comprehension, it would go on the very _right_. Only because you've done something different—replaced the statement with an expression so it's no longer part of the nested statement—does it appear otherwise.

Comment: @DonQuestion: Also, I think the tutorial section I quoted explains it more simply—because it doesn't try to add complexity that isn't actually there.

Comment: @abamert: i beg to differ. Please reread your reasoning and tone down your zeal! You rightly pointed out, that i used an expression rather then a statement, but i never argued otherwise, in fact i didn't point to that subtle difference at all. It was merely meant as a helping hand to a new python fellow and not as CS-discussion amongst peers. That my explanation is perceived as worse as any other offered, is already nicely reflected in the numbers of votes. That's what they are for.